# Unity Batch Register by convention

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

I'm trying to do the equivalent of the following Autofac code in Unity IoC.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof (DataRepository<>).Assembly)
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

This basically replaces individually registering the following:

```
DataSourceDataRepository : DataRepository<DataSource>, IDataSourceDataRepository
```

For clarity: This registers all of my Repository types as their implemented interfaces, so when i inject IDataSourceDataRepository I get a DataSourceDataRepository, etc.

In unity i've been unable to get beyond doing one at a time manually.
Test code just shows a failure to register.

My attempt:

```
container.RegisterType<RepositoryConnection>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

container.RegisterTypes(
     AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().Where(t => typeof(IRepository).IsAssignableFrom(t)), getLifetimeManager: t => new TransientLifetimeManager(),
    getInjectionMembers: t=> new InjectionConstructor[] {new InjectionConstructor(typeof(RepositoryConnection)) } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromAssemblies(typeof(DataRepository<>).Assembly)
        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository")),
    WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces);
```